# Reusable React-Toastify Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a reusable Toast Component.

here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-toastify-toast-with-react-component-forked-mu2l9c?file=/src/Toast.js:146-680

On rendering the Toast Component itself *[commented below]*, the toast pops up beautifully.

```
return (
    <>
      {/* <Toast /> */}   ---> This one works perfectly.
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        name="input"
      />
    </>
```

However, I am trying to achieve calling of toast using exposed `toastMeta` . So that the caller can simply type `toastMeta.message("please show up..")` to get the Toast. Also passing an optional param horizontal and vertical position.

**PROBLEM:** Unable to call the the toast Component using `toastMeta.message("")`

*Note: This CustomToast will be a npm package, so the caller has to install this library and import the `toastMeta`.*

```
export const toastMeta = {
  position: "top-right",
  message: "Error Toast"
};

export const Toast = ({ className, children, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ToastContainer {...props}>
        {toast.error(toastMeta.message, {
          position: toastMeta.position,
          autoClose: 3000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          theme: "colored"
        })}
      </ToastContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Calling toast after every key stroke..

```
const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    toastMeta("Error Message..");
  }, [input]);

  return (
    <>
      {/* <Toast /> */}
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        name="input"
      />
```

**Reason for creating a Toast Component:**

For version control as it is one of the component of the Common Library. The common library has all the UI elements.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cant call an object as a function, that's the one reason also the implementation is incorrect you need to use **ref** of the toast and then pass the values dynamically.

Kindly check the code, I hope this will help you out!

App.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Toast, toastMeta } from "./Toast";

const App = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const toastRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // toastMeta("Error Message..");
    if (input !== "") {
      toastRef.current.showToast({
        position: "top-right",
        message: "Custom Error Toast"
      });
    }
  }, [input]);

  return (
    <>
      <Toast ref={toastRef} />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        name="input"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Toast.js

```js
import React, { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useState } from "react";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

export const toastMeta = () => {
  return { position: "top-right", message: "Error Toast" };
};

export const Toast = forwardRef(({ className, children, ...props }, ref) => {
  const [toastConfig, setToastConfig] = useState({});

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    showToast: (_data) => {
      setToastConfig(_data);
    }
  }));

  return (
    <ToastContainer {...props}>
      {toast.error(toastConfig?.message, {
        position: toastConfig?.position,
        autoClose: 3000,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        theme: "colored"
      })}
    </ToastContainer>
  );
});
```